# Вывод на экран в виде 16.09.2013

Tags: c++, консоль, формат

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне вывести в консоли дату с таким форматом: 16.09.2013, но не 16.9.2013.

Вот мой кусок кода:

```
DATE::DATE()
:day_{ 0 }, month_{ 0 }, year_{ 0 } {}

DATE::DATE(unsigned short day, unsigned short month, unsigned short year)
: day_{ day }, month_{ month }, year_{ year } {}
DATE::DATE(DATE const & other)
: day_{ other.day_ }, month_{ other.month_ }, year_{ other.year_ } {}

void DATE::print() {
std::cout << day_ << "." << month_ << "." << year_ << std::endl;
}

void DATE::set() {
std::cout << "Установка даты\n";
std::cout << "День: ";
std::cin >> day_;
std::cout << "Месяц: ";
std::cin >> month_;
std::cout << "Год: ";
std::cin >> year_;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выводите число `n` как

```
cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << n;
```

Т.е. ширина вывода - 2 знака, недостающее дополнить нулями...

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Я совершенно забыла про iomanip...